# On Mac OSX, warning: You need Cython to compile Pyjnius

Tags: python, macos, kivy

When building for Kivy on Mac, I get this error,

```
Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/Users/lawrence/.buildozer/cache --target=/Users/rhus/KivyProjects/assisesorl-new/.buildozer/applibs pyjnius
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I followed [Kivy for iOS](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html) tutorial, also used sudo pip install cython==20.2 recommended by some posts here. I just also updated to the latest XCode and Mac terminal. It seems the latest build for Kivy is breaking.

Comment: `# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2`

Comment: You could try using an older version of xcode, I've seen other compile problems recently that apparently are solved by that for now.